# Convergence in Distribution and probability density function

Tags: distributions, convergence

I am reading the follow webpage:

http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Convergence.html

[image]

I can understand b. and c.,

but I don't understand how they get $f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 1& x=\frac{1}{n}\\ 
 0& x \neq\frac{1}{n}
\end{matrix}\right.$

I think $f_n(x)$ should always be $0$, because:

Since we know that $F_n(x)=P(X_n<x)=P(\frac{1}{n}<x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 0& x<\frac{1}{n}\\ 
 1& x \geq\frac{1}{n}
\end{matrix}\right.$

If we take derivative on $F_n$ we will get $f_n$ which should be $0$ since $F_n$ is a constant (0 or 1).

Please help to explain how they get $f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 1& x=\frac{1}{n}\\ 
 0& x \neq\frac{1}{n}
\end{matrix}\right.$ , thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand (a) at all because it looks nonsensical to me: each $X_n$ is discrete and therefore none of the $f_n$ exists!  Maybe the take-away here is to be more selective in the websites you read. :-)

Comment: "If we take derivative on Fn we will get fn which should be 0 since Fn is a constant (0 or 1).". For discrete distribution, the pdf is not general derivative of cdf. For example, binomial distribution. I do not how a) and the first note can be correct simultaneously.